# How to restrict AWS CodeCommit Repository access from other network

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

As per mentioned subject, I want to restrict my AWS CodeCommit repository from any other network and only access with my own infra network.

for eg. we restrict EC2 VM from out side the network and only allow to connect VM with our own infra network similarly I want to restrict AWS CodeCommit repository from any other network except my own network.

please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If your own network is within a AWS VPC you can use [a VPC endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/codecommit-and-interface-VPC.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a policy that restricts access coming from a specific VPC only.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Access",
            "Action": "codecommit:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceVpc": "vpc-abcdef123456789"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If you want to access the service from your on-prem network, note that the VPC in the condition above would be the one that your VPN connection is attached to (i.e. the one where the Virtual Private Gateway is attached to).

Using an Interface Endpoint for CodeCommit that is attached to your VPC, you can further increase security as that way the connection won't use the public internet (so no Internet Gateway needed) to access CodeCommit.